# SDL - правильный ввод текста

Tags: c++, sdl2, sdl

все мы знаем, что у windows и linux систем присутствует целый ряд настроек ввода текста (скорость ввода при зажатии, задержка после ввода первого символа и так далее)
К сожалению SDL_TEXTINPUT игнорирует эти настройки.
Каким образом я могу сделать ввод текста с клавиатуры, учитывая все настройки ввода?
SDK_event у меня находится в отдельном файле
моя реализация поля для ввода:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Button.h"
#include "KeyFromSym.h"
struct input : Button {
private:
    bool type = false;
public:
    input(int px, int py, int sx, int sy,
        std::string text_, bool Dynamic = true,
        std::string font_ = "Default",
        SDL_Color TextColor_ = { 0,0,0 },
        SDL_Color BackgroundColor_ = { 255,255,255 })
        : Button(px, py, sx, sy, text_, Dynamic, font_, TextColor_, BackgroundColor_)  {
        
    }
    bool Init(SDL_Renderer* ren, bool cansel) {
        if (Button::Init(ren)) {
            type = !type;
            return true;
        }
        if (cansel) {
            type = false;
        }
        if (type && e.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT) { //Ввод
            Button::retext(Button::GetText() + e.text.text);
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Лучше `SDC_TEXTINPUT` ничего нет. По идее, он должен уважать настройки ОС. Можете показать, как именно проверяли?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat дополнил

Comment: Нуу, по такому коду ничего не понятно. Какая ОС, винда? После изменения настроек приложение перезапускали?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat не работает ни на десятой винде ни на 11. Проблема очевидно не в настройках ОС, а в самой реализации, если, конечно, SDL_TEXTINPUT должен действительно работать как надо. Касаемо реализации: у нас есть класс input, который из себя представляет кнопку,но если мы на неё нажмём (Button::Init(ren) равен true если мы нажали на кнопку) то активируется режим ввода текста (type = true) и в таком случае каждый тик мы просто проверяем ввод текста(type && e.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT). В случае, если пользователь написал что-то, то его текст прибавляется к общему тексту кнопки функцией retext.

Comment: У меня на убунте все работает как надо... Не поленился, собрал под винду, запустил 10-ку в виртуалке - там тоже все правильно. На чем проверял: https://pastebin.com/BBXT0nPe

Comment: @HolyBlackCat понял свою ошибку. Оказывается, что SDL_TEXTINPUT может адекватно работать только в цикле while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) есть ли способ сделать так, чтобы я мог нормально использовать TEXTINPUT за пределами это цикла?

Comment: Что-то вы не так делаете. Вообще все евенты работают только в таком (или подобном) цикле. Вам нужно сделать вот что: завести `std::string`, каждый кадр ее очищать, потом делать цикл `while (SDL_PollEvent ...)`, в котором на `SDL_TEXTINPUT` дописывать в конец строки новые символы, а потом как-то использовать содержимое строки.

Comment: Покажите, как у вас сейчас event loop сделан?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я просто сделал всё оп вашему совету, теперь у меня есть текстовый файл, который постоянно отчищается и передаёт всё в поле для ввода, а заполняется он его через Pol event

Comment: Текстовый файл?!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat тьфу, утром писал, натупил. переменная текстовая)